# How to parse comma separated string without split using regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

The main problem that I do not have any split, match or other functions because it's not a program, I have only regexp support. The string is:

```
145,453,234
```

I extracted last value using this `([0-9]{3})(?!,)` and this works perfect.

How to deal with first two values (I need two regexps)?

Comment: What programming language are you using to code ?

Comment: >What programming language are you using to code ? Neither.

Comment: Something like `[^,]*+`?

Comment: I need using some pcre expression get 145, with other expression 453 and with other 234

Comment: So you always will have three comma separated parts?

Comment: >So you always will have three comma separated parts? Yes.

Comment: To get first: `^[^,]+`. To get second: `(?<=,)[^,]+(?=,)`. To get third: `[^,]+$`

Comment: Up vote for revo. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a regex specifically for each section you should care about boundaries. If all chars between commas are numbers then use these regexes to get each part separately:

- First part: `^\d+`
- Second part: `(?<=,)\d+(?=,)`
- Last part: `\d+$`

If it could be more than numbers use `[^,]` in place of `\d`.